# Word2Vec embedding with pyspark: missing word embedding in lookup table

Tags: python, pyspark, word2vec, word-embedding, lookup-tables

I have the dataframe below:
I want to embed with word2vec the "words" (categorical feature values) contained in the `sentence` column.

```py
df.show()
>>> +--------------------+-------+
    |            sentence|  Count|
    +--------------------+-------+
    |                 [U]|1670856|
    |              [U, U]| 882120|
    |           [U, U, U]| 550486|
    |        [U, U, U, U]| 442281|
    |     [U, U, U, U, U]| 339439|
    |  [U, U, U, U, U, U]| 284084|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, U...| 239609|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, U...| 226310|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, U...| 192604|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, U...| 189109|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, U...| 176548|
    |[U, U OTHER, U, U...| 153887|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, U...| 135189|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, U...| 124120|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, U...| 114822|
    |[U, U, U, V, U, U...| 106219|
    |[U, U, I, U, U, U...|  98360|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, U...|  92218|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, U...|  86630|
    |[U, U, U, U, U, V...|  82747|
    +--------------------+-------+
```

It contains a lot of `U`, but it is not embedding the `U`. Why? Does pyspark internally consider it as a stopword?

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2Vec

word2Vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=2, seed=42, inputCol="sentence", 
                    outputCol="model", minCount=1, maxSentenceLength=1000000, 
                    windowSize=5, numPartitions=40)
model = word2Vec.fit(df.select('sentence'))
model.getVectors().show()
>>> +-----+--------------------+
    | word|              vector|
    +-----+--------------------+
    |    V|[47.0076942443847...|
    |    I|[-16.924522399902...|
    |OTHER|[5.31341981887817...|
    +-----+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the issue but for me its working well

### Load the test data

```scala
  val documentDF = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      "U U U I".split(" "),
      "U I V OTHER".split(" "),
      "V OTHER I".split(" ")
    ).map(Tuple1.apply)).toDF("sentence")

    documentDF.show(false)
    documentDF.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----------------+
      * |sentence        |
      * +----------------+
      * |[U, U, U, I]    |
      * |[U, I, V, OTHER]|
      * |[V, OTHER, I]   |
      * +----------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- sentence: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
      */
```

### Apply `Word2Vec` with specified params

```scala
    // Learn a mapping from words to Vectors.
    val word2Vec = new Word2Vec()
      .setInputCol("sentence")
      .setOutputCol("model")
      .setVectorSize(2)
      .setSeed(42)
      .setWindowSize(5)
      .setMinCount(1)
      .setMaxSentenceLength(1000000)
      .setNumPartitions(40)
    val model = word2Vec.fit(documentDF)
    model.getVectors.show(false)

    /**
      * +-----+--------------------------------------------+
      * |word |vector                                      |
      * +-----+--------------------------------------------+
      * |U    |[0.08220049738883972,-0.14330919086933136]  |
      * |I    |[-0.03325378894805908,-0.061152905225753784]|
      * |OTHER|[0.07802027463912964,0.14332491159439087]   |
      * |V    |[-0.016965162009000778,-0.12242981046438217]|
      * +-----+--------------------------------------------+
      */
```

Comment: yes, on a smaller dataset it is working well, but if you take a huge dataframe (like 2 billions rows) with `U` being predominant, this won't work.